# How to control a dc motor?

Tags: experimental-physics, electric-circuits, voltage, electronics

I am in 8th standard and I am doing a project on 3d printing pens. I want to know how to control a dc motor, so that when I press a button it should increase its speed gradually till it reaches its maximum and when I press another button it should do the converse until it reaches its minimum. Please help me in this project. I tried it out with a spdt switch along with a resistor but did not work out as the speed suddenly increases or suddenly decreases.

Comment: The integrator circuit (using an opamp) should work. It would convert a dc to a linear wave, thereby giving a linear increase or decrease

Comment: Is the motor loaded? In that case you may need to have a feedback circuit. The most convenient implementation, these days, is with a small motor controller CPU which can measure the RPMs, calculate the necessary current trough the motor and then produce a PWM signal for your switch.

Comment: For a question like this one, you will get better answers at the electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is exactly the type of controller which is used on a lot of modern model railways.  I suggest you Google "model railway controller circuits" or something similar.